# Moved old HD to new machine with Windows 10, how to delete files?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

My old machine died. I installed the old disk as an extra disk in the new Windows 10 (old machine also was Windows 10). A lot of files I can' delete. I've tryied to take ownership of everything but some files fail. I don't need an unused windows installation in the disk. I've tried to take ownership, but it keeps asking me to that I need to be my user to delete the files.

I managed to delete some dirs following [these instructions](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/need-permission-to-delete-folder-after-windows-10/bc9c59ce-d9c1-4ebf-9662-e0c8d4fb0007), but there are still some dirs that I can't delete.

How do I gain control of everything so I can clean the disk?

Comment: Also try the instructions here to own the files.   https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security/no-administrator-rights-on-the-pc-windows-10/73cab663-31fb-423c-9e88-de1fccc89ba8

Comment: Why not just format it?

Comment: See my answer in the duplicate question :)

Comment: @DavidPostill, this isn't a duplicate question.  The answer may be the same, but the other one asks the feature of a specific program that I didn't know it exists. I never heard about Takeown and would never find the question marked as duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Still not there, but near. Open an administrator cmd shell, and type:

```
takeown /f F:\path\undeletable\folder /r /d y
ICACLS F:\path\undeletable\folder /inheritance:e /grant:r Administrador:F /T
```

Now you'll be able to delete almost all. Some folders you must enter through the explorer and, a dialog will appear, you accept it and then try to delete again.